# how to run my own external command in python script

Tags: python

I wanna to run my own non-system external commands in python.

Such as "sudo insteon on 23". Subprocess and os.system are designed for system calls.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: subprocess and os.system can be used to run any external command and typically do not run 'system calls', in fact you don't ever run system calls directly from a command line

Comment: can you give me example for this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) for this:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('sudo insteon on 23'))
proc.communicate()
```

Comment: thanks but it returns "unknow device"

Comment: Does `sudo insteon on 23` work from the command-line?

Comment: Thank you very much. I just forgot to link the usb device. I run it on VirtualBox.