# Command inside Python when name of I/O files must change

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, shlex

Ok, I have found how to execute complex commands inside Python with this post [how to run my own external command in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910870/how-to-run-my-own-external-command-in-python-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
import shlex
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('gr_cp -option=90 inputfilename outputfilename'))
proc.communicate()
```

It really works, but in my case I am executing a loop and the name of the `inputfilename` and the `outputfilename` change in each iteration. I have tried that solution but it doesn't work because it does not recognize `inputfilename`.

In the loop, `inputfilename` is `mbr{:03}_20161110.grb1.format(i)` where the `i` is running in the loop from 1 to 21.

Thank you.

*EDIT:* As requested, here it goes how the loop is:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    dn = './mbr{:03}'.format(i)
    inputfilename = 'mbr{:03}_2016111000.grb1'.format(i) 
    os.chdir(dn)
    #do some things copying and concatenating files
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('gr_cp -option=90 inputfilename outfilename'))
    proc.communicate()
    os.chdir('..')
```

the loop explores directories `mbr001` to `mbr020` and goes naming the `inputfile` as each parent directory.

The gr_cp is a command line tool that extracts some variables from `inputfilename` to `outputfilename` (like a filter). It is like any other shell command. The problem is that in a loop it doesn't identify `inputfilename`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the loop? Also `inputfilename` and `outputfilename` are missing in your example...

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that inside the loop `inputfilename` and `outputfilename` are 2 variables holding the names of you (resp.) input and output file, just do:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('gr_cp -option=90') + [ inputfilename, outputfilename ])
```

(because the output of `shlex.split` is a list of string, so you can just add the last members of the list...)

Comment: Thanks. `inputfilename` is a variable, yes, as you can see in the loop. `outfilename` is like `inputfilename` but reduced (with less data, that's what `gr_cp` does). So, I suppose the more logical is to name `outputfilename` as "filtered_inputfilename" (to add the prefix "filtered").